# Why is Voldemort so dumb?

Tags: harry-potter

This was always odd to me, if Voldemort wanted his Horcruxes safe, why didn't he just turn his Horcrux into a grain of rice and leave it in the middle of the safari? And I know that Voldemort is a trophy collector or whatever, **but this was his soul we're talking about**! Surely he could use something unsuspecting?

I mean come on Voldemort, your mother's old house and the Room of Requirement, did he really think they were good places to hide ***his frickn' soul***? I mean you may question the diary but no one really suspects it and it's used as more of a weapon than a safe guard.

Also in the *Chamber of Secrets* 16 year old Tom Riddle said this:

> 'You're dead Harry Potter,' said Riddle's voice above him. 'Dead. Even Dumbledore's bird knows it. Do you see what he's doing, Potter? He's crying'.

And then when Fawkes heals him Voldy's just like, oh yeah... phoenix tears.

How can he be so powerful and yet so dumb?

Comment: JK Rowling needed him to be dumb, and *voila*, dumb he became.

Comment: @Valorum The question is more than about Horcruxes. I'm not really sure this is a dupe.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - It seems sufficiently similar to me. Why didn't Voldemort make better horcruxes and hide them better

Comment: I've added a second link regarding his choice of *object*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

His own pride is his downfall.

Dumbledore addresses this:

> "And they could be anything?" said Harry. "They could be oh, in tin cans or, I dunno, empty potion bottles..."
> "You are thinking of Portkeys, Harry, which must be ordinary objects, easy to overlook. But would Lord Voldemort use tin cans or old potion bottles to guard his own precious soul? You are forgetting what I have showed you. Lord Voldemort liked to collect trophies, and he preferred objects with a powerful magical history His pride, his belief in his own superiority, his determination to carve for himself a startling place in magical history; these things, suggest to me that Voldemort would have chosen his Horcruxes with some care, favouring objects worthy of the honour."
> "The diary wasn't that special."
> "The diary, as you have said yourself, was proof that he was the heir of Slytherin. I am sure that Voldemort considered it of stupendous importance."
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, chapter 23: "insert chapter title here"</sub>

Voldemort's pride is what makes him decide to use grandiose objects for his Horcruxes. He's so overconfident that he didn't take Phoenix tears into account. It's why he battled Harry himself in the graveyard.

Voldemort's pride clouds his judgment and has always been his downfall.

Comment: Maybe you want to address the phoenix too: First it is Voldemort at the age of 16, still learning, and second: Tears will not be something Voldemort is seeing power in, more likely weakness, so he probably never researched for this on himself

Comment: @Allerleirauh Volvemort obviously knows about the magical properties of Phoenix tears, because he just realized right after. As Mithical said, pride clouds his judgement, leading Voldemort to make mistakes or oversights.